# Is there a postman collection for AutoDesk forge?

Tags: api, postman, autodesk-forge

The forge API does not offer an OpenAPI or swagger file.

So did anybody yet create a more or less complete postman collection for the different forge APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can find it here https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/my-postman-collection 
We also have another resource to handle 3legged authentication from Postman - https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3-legged-authentication-postman